# .Net Core 2.0 Webservice and TLS 1.2/certificate

Tags: .net, ssl, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to setup a webservice using .NET Core 2.0 running in Docker. Since I don't have much experience with core I did some research, found soapcore and was able to run a webservice in docker.

```
    public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<SampleService>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseSoapEndpoint<SampleService>("/Service.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer);
        app.UseSoapEndpoint<SampleService>("/Service.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

I also found a couple of resources on how to implement TLS, but they seem to be a little outdated since they all refere to some *project.json*-file which seems to be outdated.

Long story short: is there someone who could point me in the right direction or explain to me where and how I could establish TLS in my application, put my certificates and such?

Best
Gerrit